# Derby migration fail during Artifactory upgrade from 6 to 7

Tags: artifactory

I am upgrading Artifactory from 5.5.1 to latest 7.35 using [manual](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory?utm_source=platform&utm_content=installer#UpgradingArtifactory-RPMUpgrade).
Until 6.x major it went well, but after trying to migrate from 6.12.2 or 6.23.21 to different 7.x majors it always ends up in bad state. I tried migrating it from different 6.x versions to different 7.x versions, nothing helped.

`migration.sh` always shows success, but after starting Artifactory it stucks in broken state with no UI accessible. However `localhost:8081` still redirects to `localhost:8082/ui`.

This can be seen in `derby.log`. Looks like database migration problem.

```
# cat derby.log
----------------------------------------------------------------
Fri Mar 11 14:30:23 UTC 2022:
Booting Derby version The Apache Software Foundation - Apache Derby - 10.14.2.0 - (1828579): instance a816c00e-017f-7963-434f-00001e025fc0
on database directory /var/opt/jfrog/artifactory/data/derby with class loader java.net.URLClassLoader@4f970963
Loaded from file:/opt/jfrog/artifactory/app/artifactory/tomcat/lib/derby-10.14.2.0.jar
java.vendor=AdoptOpenJDK
java.runtime.version=11.0.2+9
user.dir=/
os.name=Linux
os.arch=amd64
os.version=3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64
derby.system.home=null
derby.stream.error.file=/opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/log/derby.log
Database Class Loader started - derby.database.classpath=''
Fri Mar 11 14:30:41 UTC 2022 Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main] (XID = 176494570), (SESSIONID = 3), (DATABASE = /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/derby), (DRDAID = null), Cleanu
p action starting
Fri Mar 11 14:30:41 UTC 2022 Thread[localhost-startStop-1,5,main] (XID = 176494570), (SESSIONID = 3), (DATABASE = /opt/jfrog/artifactory/var/data/artifactory/derby), (DRDAID = null), Failed
Statement is: INSERT INTO access_configs (config_name, modified, data) VALUES (?, ?, ?) with 3 parameters begin parameter #1: shared.security.joinKey :end parameter begin parameter #2: 164
7009041746 :end parameter begin parameter #3: BLOB:Length=93 :end parameter
ERROR 23505: The statement was aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique or primary key constraint or unique index identified by 'ACCESS_CONFIGS_PK' defined on
'ACCESS_CONFIGS'.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.insertAndCheckDups(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.doInsert(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexChanger.insert(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.IndexSetChanger.insert(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.RowChangerImpl.insertRow(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.InsertResultSet.normalInsertCore(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.execute.InsertResultSet.open(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.executeStmt(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericPreparedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeLargeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedPreparedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor58.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.StatementFacade$StatementProxy.invoke(StatementFacade.java:114)
at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy81.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at org.jfrog.storage.JdbcHelper.executeUpdate(JdbcHelper.java:229)
at org.jfrog.access.server.db.util.AccessJdbcHelperImpl.executeUpdate(AccessJdbcHelperImpl.java:104)
```

Any ideas for debugging this?
Thank you kindly for your help.

Comment: is it an RPM upgrade? if so, the steps are vrey straightforward with no migrate.sh needed. Migrate.sh is needed only when the upgrade method is linux archive as mentioned here https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Upgrading+Artifactory?utm_source=platform&utm_content=installer#UpgradingArtifactory-LinuxArchiveUpgrade

Comment: Please also check the router-service.log if you see any statement as "all services started successfully". Try to run this curl command as well "curl http://localhost:8046/router/api/v1/system/health"

Comment: It's an RPM upgrade. Migrate.sh executes automaticly during the upgrade. Thank you for your answer, I will investigate `router-service.log`,